# PJSUA2: Contact header uri length limit

Tags: android, pjsip, pjsua2

I'm building an android VOIP application with push notifications support, based on PJSUA2.

I need to send the push notification (FCM) token to the server (Asterisk in my case) as contact uri parameter, so that I can retrieve it with a script from the server and send notification to wake up client before sending an incoming call request.

I put the parameters in the contact uri parameters with

```java
acfg.getSipConfig().setContactUriParams(buildParams(contactParameters));
```

`contactParams` is a `HashMap<String, String>` with parameters name and value, while `buildParams` is the following method:

```java
private String buildParams(Map<String, String> params) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (String k : params.keySet()) {
        builder.append(';');
        builder.append(k);
        String v = params.get(k);
        if (v != null && v.trim().length() > 0) {
            builder.append("=\"");
            builder.append(v);
            builder.append('\"');
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

without FCM parameters everything works well, but

- building the contact uri with the following parameters
  `;pn-provider="fcm";pn-tok="LONG FCM TOKEN"`
  makes the calls hangup after 32 seconds (see question [PJSUA2 Android - Incoming calls drop after 32 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56093536/pjsua2-android-incoming-calls-drop-after-32-seconds))
- removing `;pn-provider="fcm"` works
- sending just a portion of the token works (in pn-tok, together with the pn-provider parameter)

I thought it may be a "invalid characters issue", but it actually seems to be a "max length issue".

Is there a Contact header max length or a URI max length for Contact header? If yes, is it a PJSIP limit or a SIP limit?

Comment: How did you work around this issue? I am working on a react native app using pjsip lib and when creating an account with the long `pn-tok` raises an exception. Let me know. Thanks

Comment: I didn't work around this issue in a stable way yet. At the moment I applied a patch to increase the maximum contact uri length to 512 or 768 (https://github.com/VoiSmart/pjsip-android-builder), but it only seems to work if I only add the "pn-tok" parameter (without other pn-* parameters). If I just add the pn-provider parameter, the issue comes again. I think there is some other issue in the app or server side, but I didn't find it yet. I obtained this behaviour with both PJSUA 2.8 and 2.9 in conjunction with Asterisk 13.